# Thread.join freezes progressbar

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a code which uses a thread to run multiple progress bar.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(progressbar1);
thread1.start(); 
thread2.start()
```

And so on. After I have

```
thread1.join(); 
thread2.join(); 
thread3.join();
```

But that freezes all three progress bar animation and shows the completion only when all threads are done.
How to solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Doing any blocking operation on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) will cause your GUI to become unresponsive and stop being repainted.  That's why long-running operations should be done in a background thread.

It seems like you know you need to do things in a background thread but still want to block the EDT.  You shouldn't do that.  Instead, you want a callback--some code that will be run once your background threads have finished running.

An already provided callback mechanism available in Java 6+ is [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).  Implement a worker, putting the `join()`s (and `start()`s) in the `doInBackground()` method.  Then any Swing operations that you want to do afterward can go in `done()`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I have no idea what you mean by blocking UI thread. I just started learning about threads.

Comment: The UI thread (or EDT) is the thread that is responsible for processing UI events (e.g. mouse clicks) and redrawing the screen.  Blocking the UI thread simply means getting it to do something that takes a long time to complete.  For example `join()` causes the thread to wait until the "joined" thread finishes ... which could take a relatively long time.  The harm in blocking is that no other UI events are processed during that time; i.e. the UI becomes unresponsive.  (The length of "a long time" is subjective, but you'll know it when you see it.)

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking the UI thread. You shouldn't do that. Options:

- Have *another* thread which just calls `join` on the first three. Wasteful in terms of creating another resource, but reasonably straightforward.
- Use a counter - making sure that you use something like `AtomicInteger` to ensure that you don't run into memory model and race condition issues. Start the counter at 3, and decrement it at the end of each thread When the last thread finishes its work (i.e. its decrement puts the counter to 0), make *it* call back into the UI.

(The second bullet may be what you were doing already... it's hard to tell for sure given the description of just "I used a counter.")

While I entirely see where you're coming from in terms of the control flow of the application being much harder in an event-driven world, that's the way Swing works (and it's the way most other UI frameworks work, too). You simply *can't* block the UI thread. (This is also why C# 5 is making it all easier at the *language* level...)

Comment: I used a counter to track how many of the threads were done. When all threads are done, I then doSomething(). But I want the next line after thread1.start(); thread2.start() doSomething(). But the progressbar all freeze.

Comment: @LewsTherin: You'll need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` from whichever thread finishes last to call `doSomething`. Basically you *can't* do anything long-running in the UI thread.