# How does Synchronized work?

Tags: java, swing

I really don't like posting multiple questions in a go, sorry if this is annoying.

I finally managed to fix my problem. Except I'm not sure if it is reliable or even wise.

```
   public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            float time = 0.01f;
            try {
                while(time < timer)
                {
                       time+=0.1f;
                                       Thread.sleep(100);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        synchronized (ProgressBar.class) {
            int val =++ProgressBar.threadCount;
            if(val == 10)
            {
                                System.out.println("All threads are finished!") ;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I've been testing for 5mins now, and it seems to work. 
But can someone explain what's happening? When a thread is started, it makes sure that the synchronized block is not in use, otherwise it waits for it to be completed.
So is it some queueing system?
Thanks again.
EDIT:

Previous links
[How does AtomicInteger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148823/how-does-atomicinteger-work)

[Thread.join freezes progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144537/thread-join-freezes-progressbar)

Comment: What's up with the downvotes? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: I haven't voted, but I have my problems with this question.  You refer to an earlier question but do not link to it (do you expect me to search for it?).  You do not explain what the code is supposed to be doing.  Your code sample does not show how your threads are created, nor does it show what ProgressBar in your case is.

Comment: Read - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: @ibid I will edit my questions to reflect that. My bad. 
Anyways the code is supposed to execute a function *only* after all 10 progress bars are done.

Comment: Lews, I'm still not sure what you are asking beyond the direct question "So is it some queueing system?" which I hope my answer below addresses.

Comment: Use high-level constructs. You want a countdown latch: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html.

Comment: @ibid by queuing system I mean do all threads wait for a thread to finish with the synchronized block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `synchronized` block uses the lock in the object that it refers to, in your case `ProgressBar.class`.  If no other thread owns the lock, the `synchronized` block acquires it and proceeds.  If the lock already is owned by another thread, the `synchronized` block goes to sleep to await the release of the lock, at which point it tries again.  Once the thread that owns the lock finishes with the `synchronized` block, it releases the lock, which causes at least one of the threads that are waiting for the lock to attempt to acquire it.

(This explanation overlooks the possibility that the same thread may acquire a lock several times before releasing it.  So long as the thread owns the lock at least once, all other threads are blocked from acquiring it.)

See [the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html).

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I want to know. 
I have a lock that stops the another thread from incrementing the counter. Forcing other threads to wait before it can use that block of code. As long as it doesn't indefinitely then it's fine I guess. Thanks